# Is it possible for the user to use an ActiveX control which is unknown for application?

Tags: delphi

I actually want to import an activeX control while it's not installed on Delphi and its class is not specific. I actually want to import and use ActiveX controls on runtime without importing them in delphi IDE. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure that I have understood your needs, but it might be really simple: Drop a `TOLEContainer` on your form, and make it `Align := alClient`. Then do

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OleContainer1.InsertObjectDialog;
end;
```

This will allow the user to insert any registered (on the user's machine) OLE control in the `TOLEContainer`.

Comment: EXACTLY what I wanted. Thanks mate.